# Check if a flag is set on an enum field in Azure Cognitive Search using OData Query Syntax

Tags: c++, odata, azure-cognitive-search

I have to find a way to query (am using Azure search) whether or not a field has a set of flags set without using bitwise and. The reason for the limitation is that Azure Cognitive Search uses OData for querying, which does not support any bitwise operations.

Say we have an enum like so:

```
public enum PreferredColors
{
     red = 1,
     blue = 2,
     green = 4,
     yellow = 8
}
```

Now say I have a user who prefers yellow, blue, and red. I'm want to check for users that prefer yellow and red. Normally you would do that like so:

```
PreferredColors preference = PreferredColors.red | PreferredColors.yellow
bool res = (preference & user.ColorPreferences) == preference
```

Where `res` is the result we're looking for. This check has to be part of the query (for paging reasons). Is there any other way I can perform this check that avoids using bitwise &?

Comment: Pop quiz: if you use `|` instead, and the bit is already set, what value do you get?

Comment: `without using bitwise &?` `which does not support bitwise operations.` So without `&` or without any bitwise operations?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid it?

Comment: Is bitwise & the only operator you are not alowed to use? What about other bitwise operators, bit shifts or / operator? As long you are alowed to use at least one of this, there is a way, defenetly not the best.

Comment: Without bitwise operators, you could simulate bitshifts using multiplication/division by 2 to shift bits left/right, respectively.  And then check if the result is even/odd using a modulus operator, or bitshifts

Comment: @SamVarshavchik You get the bit. Why?

OData queries do not support ANY bitwise operators, unfortunately. I have a feeling I'm SOL. But I imagine somebody has had to solve this issue in the past...

Comment: Can you use logical operators like > and < ? That way you can check if your enum variables are higher than 0

Comment: No, you don't get the bit. If your value is 10, and you `|` it with 2, the result is not 2. Try a thought experiment. Do an `|` operation with values that already have the bit set, and ones that don't, and see if a pattern emerges.

Comment: Doesn't odata have `has` to check for one bit in an enum?

Comment: Indeed, I think your real question is [How to Use Enumeration types in OData](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/odata/tutorial-sample-use-enumeration-types-in-odata/) (Pay special attention to the third paragraph)

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Apologies, you get the combined positive bits. 011 | 100 = 111. I'm still not sure the relevance if your inquiry, since I can't use any bitwise operators.

Comment: Azure Cognitive Search does not support OData enums; You'll have to model that field in your index as a different type. Will work on an example and post it shortly

Comment: @Brettyoke49 Is your example correct? It looks like the user's color preferences have to exactly match the stored preference. Shouldn't it be: bool res = (preference & user.ColorPreferences) == user.ColorPreferences

Comment: @BruceJohnston I believe my example is correct. If we do your example where preference = 1, 4, 8 and user.ColorPreferences = 1, 4 we would get a result of true. However, the user did not meet the expected criteria of the search.

Comment: @CássioRenan Sadly it doesn't seem that Azure Cognitive search accepts 'has' as an operator, even though OData does :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Cognitive Search doesn't support OData enums, so you'll have to model this scenario with a different data type than Edm.Int32. Depending on how you want to model things in your application, you could use either Collection(Edm.Int32) or maybe Collection(Edm.String). Let's use a string collection for these examples just for the sake of clarity.

Another thing you can't do in Azure Cognitive Search is compare one field of an index to another field, so I'm going to assume that the desired color preferences are known to the application code and can be injected into the query string that you're going to send to Azure Cognitive Search. The scenario is that for any given document in the search index, you want to check whether all of the preferred colors given to the application are present in the colors for that document.

Here's how you would express this query using a string collection field if the color preferences to search for are 'red' and 'green':

```
$filter=preferences/any(p: p eq 'red') and preferences/any(p: p eq 'green')
```

If you have a document where the `preferences` field contains `["green", "yellow", "red"]` for example, then the above query will match.

Comment: Hi Bruce, thanks for your answer. Is there a clean way to do a many-to-many scenario? Right now in the database, a user can prefer several colors. Say they prefer red, green, and yellow.  We would then store 13 for their preference value. If I wanted to search for anyone who prefers red and green, I would normally do their preference & 5. Is there any not-unpleasant way to model this logic? In reality, there are closer to ~15 enum values than 4, so writing a ton of separate checks is not ideal.

Comment: It's not *that* unpleasant, but you will need to list all the user's preferences separately. I'll update my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Actually, I'm still unclear on your scenario. In the example you gave, which value is in the search index, 13 or 5?

Comment: 13 is in the search index. Meaning they prefer yellow, green, and red. We're searching with a value of 5, which means we want anyone who prefers (at least) red and green.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited my answer accordingly.